# Harvest files from multiple directories in wix with HeatDirectory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wix, installation, heat

So far, I was doing this to harvest files from single directory:

```
<HeatDirectory DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" OutputFile="references.wxs" 
  Directory="../MyProject/reference1" ComponentGroupName="ref1" 
  ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" PreprocessorVariable="var.ref1" 
  AutogenerateGuids="true">
</HeatDirectory>
```

How can I harvest files from multiple directories into one .wxs file with HeatDirectory like below:

```
<HeatDirectory OutputFile="references.wxs" 
  Directory="directory1_Path|Directory2_Path|...." ComponentGroupName="ref1" 
  ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" AutogenerateGuids="true">
</HeatDirectory>
```

Is there some way to do it or do I need to have multiple HeatDirectory elements in my wixproject file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HeatDirectory` (as its name implies) only harvests one directory (and optionally its children) at a time. To harvest two directory roots, you'll need two `HeatDirectory` elements. You'll also need to output two different `.wxs` files otherwise one harvest action will overwrite the other's output file.

Comment: ahhh, why shouldn't I read this before :(. from HarvestDirectory documentation (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html), I was confused and using two HDirectory targets and one HeatDirectory task for both..

Answer (score 0):

Refer to @Farrukh Waheed comment, you can do something like below:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include="../Project1">
      <DirectoryRefId>Ref1</DirectoryRefId>
      <ComponentGroupName>Component1</ComponentGroupName>
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <HarvestDirectory Include="../Project2">
      <DirectoryRefId>Ref2</DirectoryRefId>
      <ComponentGroupName>Component2</ComponentGroupName>
    </HarvestDirectory>
  </ItemGroup>
```